# Get all keys from array of (different) objects type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, keyof

I have a type FooBar, that contains objects with different props. I want to get the keys from all objects. I thought that could be obtained by using `keyof FooBar[number];` but it only returns the common keys.

```
type FooBar = [
  {
    foo: "hello";
    bar: "goodbye";
  },
  {
    foo: "hi";
    bar: "goodbye";
    fizz: "buzz";
  }
];

type FooBarKeys = keyof FooBar[number];

// type FooBarKeys = "foo" | "bar"
```

How do I get all keys for all the objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type Index<T> = {[k in keyof T]: k}  // ["0", "1"]
type Props<T> = {[k in keyof Index<T>]: keyof T[k]}  // ["foo"|"bar", "foo"|"bar"|"fizz"]
type Keys = Props<FooBar>[number];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAQgQwE5QLxQNoFgBQUUA3gUUQGYIBcUARABYQA2zcdA3GeQEZq10A5ggAmPEBE7cAvgBpupQuSpwBDAJZSlRPqgHC4YiVvJQK6gF4WBPAK5WTUaQQC6XfAVCQoASQB2IhAAHgA8ACoAfJgk2ADWUOp%20ULEQIHAUUGEutLHO%20F7QAAqocGAAzuFRWMRxCUkpaRn%20gaGR2cmp6ZlxLnkFUADSqWXRxaUV8EhoEdh%20tgC2PBCobgRr%20eDQzcFhEGXA0duhkyioEe79Y%20W7%206Ml5SEn0%205AA)